# Making a add-on in Firefox to copy YouTube URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make a firefox extension where, if a link to a **youtube** video is right-clicked, there is an option to copy the video URL in the context menu.

main.js

```
exports.main = function() {
    require("sdk/context-menu").Item({
        label: "Watch in MPC",
        context:  require("sdk/context-menu").SelectorContext("a[href]"), 
        contentScriptFile: require("sdk/self").data.url("check-node.js"),
        onMessage: function(msg){},
    });
};
```

check-node.js

```
self.on("context", function(node){
    if (node.href) return true;
});
```

How would i go about detecting that the link is indeed a youtube video link and then its URL?

I am using the Add-On Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should work, I guess:

```
const ytl = /^https?:\/\/(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?)/;
self.on("context", function(node){
    return ytl.test(node.href);
});
```